# get data (single value) from ksoap to andorid through webservice

Tags: ksoap

```
final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/get_data2";
final String OPERATION_NAME = "get_data2";
final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "****";
final String req_no, req_date, bolnumber, container_no, current_loc, truck_no;
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
try 
{
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapObject resultsString = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
    Log.d("-----------------------", resultsString.getProperty("emp_name").toString());
    tv.setText(resultsString.getPropertyCount());
}     
catch (Exception exception) 
{
    exception.printStackTrace();
    tv.setText(exception.toString());           
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: it give me null pointer exception when calling soap for getting value

Comment: So please add this to your question. For more - the exception happens during "httpTransport.call(.." or "envelope.getResponse" or "resultsString.getProperty" or "tv.setText"?

Comment: It is ger propoerty

Comment: Could you add result of exception.toString() to your question so that we don't have "discuss" what might be obvious from the exception..

Comment: I finally solves the question, thank you very much for your time ! and sorry for the mass here this is first time posting a new question in statckoverflow thank you again my dear I really appriciete you guys.          This is Omar alnaim from Saudi Arabia Pieace ^_^

Comment: Could you reveal also to us what was the problem?

Comment: It is from asp.net side the webservice

Comment: Ok, this was the source "It is from asp.net side the webservice" - but what was null, what was not present?